# jenkins doesn't generate the builds automatically using local git repository

Tags: jenkins

In my system i create a local git repository and i clone the bitbucket central repository and perform all the operation  well.

Now i am trying to generate build automatically whenever there is a push is from local git repository to bitbucket repository for that i download the git plugin and installed in the jenkins and i provide my local git repository address as the source code management and i marked the build trigger "Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket".

But it doesn't generate the builds automatically if i click manually "build now" button then it generates.

can you please hemp to me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure a hook in Bitbucket so it can tell Jenkins when someone pushed new code.

Have you tried following this tutorial:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Jenkins+hook+management

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes "Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket" doesn't work properly. Rather than use Polling to bitbucket every minute

[image]

You have to write 5 * symbol separate by spaces.